# Unable to resolve warnings in revtex4-2 file

Tags: floats, captions, subcaption, warnings, revtex

Unable to resolve these two warnings in my `revtex4-2` file

Package caption Warning: Unknown document class (or package), standard defaults will be used. See the caption package documentation for explanation.

I have to use captions for subfiguers, however cannot figure out why this warning is coming

‪/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty‬
A float is stuck (cannot be placed) on input line 583.

This second warning is coming at the line \section{} where I am not using any float option.

Currently using the following packages:

```
\documentclass[%
reprint,

amsmath,amssymb,
aps,
pra,
floatfix,
]{revtex4-2}
%

\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files

\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point

\usepackage{amssymb}% for tick mark

\usepackage{bm}% bold math

\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
```

Comment: The `caption` package (loaded by `subcaption`) is not compatible with `revtex`. IIRC you can use `subfig`.

Comment: As @campa says, you should `\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}`. The syntax for subfloats is not the same as with `subcaption`, but you find several examples on the site.

Comment: Resolved the issue of subfigures. However, this warning is not going anywhere A float is stuck (cannot be placed) on input line 223. where line 223 is like this  `\begin{equation}\label{e1}
\mathrm{U}(z,T)=C \left( z^2-z_s^2 \right)^2-d \left( \frac{z^3}{3}-z_{s}^{2}z \right),
\end{equation}`